# How do I take actions every step in Veins?

Tags: omnet++

I am using Veins to implement a scenario in which I shall update a vehicle's route every time step characterized by the `step` selfmsg. In which module shall I find this behavior? I want to add some more functions to this module in the application layer by extending it. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that SUMO updates the positions of all vehicles at exactly the same time. By extension, Veins (I am assuming you are using version 4a2) will update the OMNeT++ positions of all vehicles at exactly the same time. See the [Veins tutorial demo application](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L87) for how to execute code whenever the position changes. Indeed, this will make sure that all code is running within in a single OMNeT++ event, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir. Sorry for not mentioning but I am using Veins 3.0. Yes, I was describing this event in OMNeT++, characterized by the selfmsg `step` in which the `TraCIScenarioManager` module reports the subscriptions and updates node positions. I was just unable to figure out where I should code to create this sync of events. Now, I think I have to write a method similar to `handlePositionUpdate()` to do that, as I perceive.

Comment: You are right. The same approach works in Veins 3.0 as well. Just insert the code you want to run after each time step in your application layer module, e.g., [line 87 of TraCIDemo11p](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L87)